# Should I run a multivaraite regression if dependent variable is uncorrelated with all the features

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression

I am trying to build a model to predict the returns of a stock.
I have a dataset containing 63 features that include various indicators that are all numerical. The regression model gave me a very low rsquared value of -0.09. When i viewed the correlation matrix, it showed that the target ouput had a low correlation with all of the features. Was this the reason for the poor model?

Are there possible ways to improve the model? Or would another ML model work beter such a neural nets for this kind of data?

Comment: It is difficult for a regression model to report a negative $R^2.$  Is this the adjusted $R^2,$ or an $R^2$ based on a holdout test set, or perhaps it's a model without an intercept?

Comment: @whuber I used the r2 score from sklearn.metrics.r2_score¶. The docs says :  (coefficient of determination) regression score function.

Best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be arbitrarily worse). A constant model that always predicts the expected value of y, disregarding the input features, would get a  score of 0.0.

Comment: I specified that the model should have an intercept but the value is still negative

Comment: Is it possible to also share your code?